# "...Году/годах соответственно": единственное или множественное число?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, даты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в единственном или множественном числе употребляется слово "год" в следующем предложении с "соответственно"?

*Брат и сестра родились в 1987 и 1989 **году/годах** соответственно.*

Comment: Так писать не надо, потому что грамматика такая, как в: *Брат и сестра купили хлеб и йогурт соответственно.* По грамматике совместное действие, а "соответственно" пытается это нейтрализовать, получается нестыковка. Или вот, немного другой ракурс: *Брат и сестра ходили на танцы и рисование соответственно.*